# Create a typemap for a function that returns through arguments

Tags: java, c, swig

I am converting C api > Java, and I have the following function prototype.

```
/*
 Retrieves an individual field value from the current Line
 \param reader pointer to Text Reader object.
 \param field_num relative field [aka column] index: first field has index 0.
 \param type on completion this variable will contain the value type.
 \param value on completion this variable will contain the current field value.
 \return 0 on failure: any other value on success.
 */

extern int gaiaTextReaderFetchField (gaiaTextReaderPtr reader, int field_num, int *type, const char **value);
```

I would like to get the status returned as expected, return the "type" as an int and "value" as a string (not to be deallocated)

From documentation I have found that you create a couple of structs that can retain the returned values.

Could someone please help make this first one with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your function declaration exists in a file called header.h you can do something like:

```
%module test

%{
#include "header.h"
%}

%inline %{
  %immutable;
  struct FieldFetch {
    int status;
    int type;
    char *value;
  };
  %mutable;

  struct FieldFetch gaiaTextReaderFetchField(gaiaTextReaderPtr reader, int field_num) {
    struct FieldFetch result;
    result.status = gaiaTextReaderFetchField(reader, field_num, &result.type, &result.value);
    return result;
  }
%}

%ignore gaiaTextReaderFetchField;
%include "header.h"
```

This hides the "real" `gaiaTextReaderFetchField` and instead substitutes a version that returns both of the output parameters and the result of the call in an (unmodifiable) struct.

(You could make the return status being 0 cause an exception to be thrown instead if you'd rather, using `%javaexception` instead of placing it in the struct)

Comment: Hi @Flexo,
I have only just returned to this recently and I have another issue with the gaiaTextReaderPtr struct. I was hoping maybe you could help me again, it is another piece to the puzzle.

I have created a seperate question for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132617/create-a-typemap-for-a-function-part-2